# Getting weird output when practising using pointer in c

Tags: c, loops, pointers

Here is my programme:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tokenCopy(char* dest, const char* src, int destSize)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < destSize-1; i++) {
        if (src[i] != '\0' && src[i] != EOF && src[i] != ' '){
            dest[i] = src[i];
        } else {
            dest[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[5];
    int n = tokenCopy(buff, "This is a string", 5);
    printf("%d '%s'\n", n, buff);
}
```

I tried to use this to copy extract a string from a string to another string. With this test case, I supposed to get `4 'This'`. But I get `4 'This�'` instead. I know somehow my loop terminates an index later than it supposed to be, but I do not know how to fix it.

I know there is built in function could help me with this situation, but I really want to find out the problem, thanks

Comment: @iwin : It won't work. If the destination buffer is 50 bytes long and we copy a 12 char string into it, characters from index 12 to 50 will be garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop will run until it's complete (the `else` case inside the loop will never happen), and then you just return from the function without adding the terminator to the destination string.

You need to add the terminator *after* the loop, not in the `else` inside the loop.

---

The fixed function should look like

```
int tokenCopy(char* dest, const char* src, int destSize)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < destSize-1; i++) {
        if (src[i] != '\0' && src[i] != ' '){
            dest[i] = src[i];
        } else {
            // Don't terminate here, just break out of the loop
            break;
        }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';  // Terminate string
    return i;
}
```

Note that I also removed the `EOF` check, it's pretty much useless as no standard input function should put it in the array it writes to. There's also the problem that comparing the *`int`* value `-1` (which is what `EOF` expands to) to the `char` value `-1` will not work as you expect. If you check most input functions that returns characters, you will see that they return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function does not insert the `\0` in the end of the string. `destSize` value is 5, so once you copy the `s` character, the next iteration will stop the loop because `i` will be inferior to `destsize - 1`, so the `else` clause will not be processed.

To bypass this, you should insert `\0` after the `for` loop, like this :

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < destSize-1; i++) {
    if (src[i] != '\0' && src[i] != EOF && src[i] != ' '){
        printf("Copy %c\n", src[i]);
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
}

dest[i] = '\0';

return i;
```

Also, your condition `src[i] != EOF` is useless. You main function is not standard too, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and it must return a value.